# Creating Xlines in AutoCad 2019 using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I am making Excel VBA code for AutoCad to create a simple Xline.

I made circles and lines, but Xline cancels out at the last moment.

The code will go through all the steps, it plugs in Xline, then centers it as 0,0 but then it has an issue with the specify through point.

```
Sub xline()

    Set wshShell = VBA.CreateObject("wscript.shell")

    SetCursorPos 300, 300
    SetCursorPos 600, 990
      
    Call LeftClick
      
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    wshShell.SendKeys "xline"
    wshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

    wshShell.SendKeys "v"
    wshShell.SendKeys "~"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

    wshShell.SendKeys "0,0"
    
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

    wshShell.SendKeys "~"

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    'wshShell.SendKeys "1"
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    'wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    'wshShell.SendKeys "90"
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    'wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    'wshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

     wshShell.SendKeys "{ESC}"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using WSH to issue keystrokes to the AutoCAD application and rely upon the timing of the interaction, why not interface directly with the AutoCAD Object Model?

Here is some very rough code to get you going in the right direction:

```
Sub XLine()
    Dim acApp As Object
    Dim acDoc As Object
    Dim arrBpt(0 To 2) As Double
    Dim arrVec(0 To 2) As Double

    On Error Resume Next
    Set acApp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
    If Err Then
        On Error GoTo error_handler
        Set acApp = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo error_handler
    If acApp.Documents.Count = 0 Then
        Set acDoc = acApp.Documents.Add
    Else
        Set acDoc = acApp.ActiveDocument
    End If

    arrVec(0) = 0: arrVec(1) = 1: arrVec(2) = 0
    acDoc.ModelSpace.AddXline arrBpt, arrVec
    acApp.Visible = True

error_handler:
    If Not acApp Is Nothing Then Set acApp = Nothing
End Sub
```